# JQuery: Get length of JSON reply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

In a JQuery `getJSON` call, how can I tell the length of the JSON that's returned?

```
function refreshRoomList() {
    $.getJSON('API/list_rooms',
          function (rooms) {
              if (rooms.length > 0) {
                  $("#existing-room-list").empty();
                  $("#join-existing-room").text("Join existing room:"); // this shouldn't be here
                  $.each(rooms, function (index, roomName) {
                      var newChild = sprintf('<li><a href="room?key=%s">%s</a></li>', index, roomName);
                      $("#existing-room-list").append(newChild);
                  });
              }
              else {
                  $("#join-existing-room").text("No rooms found.");
              }
          });
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work, but if I replace `rooms.length > 0` with `true`, the full list of rooms is printed out.

If `rooms` is empty, it is returned as `{}`.

Comment: Is the JSON payload returned inside square brackets `[]` or curly `{}`?

Comment: What's wrong with `users.length` ?

Comment: I think I'm using it wrong. See above.

Comment: @Rosarch: this can be due to `$.each` being able to operate on both arrays and object [literals]. Again, we would need to know whether the JSON payload is returned with square brackets `[]` (i.e. array syntax) or curly `{}` (i.e. object literal syntax) to be certain.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was sarcasm. It's being returned in object literal syntax.

Comment: @Rosarch: woops, didn't mean to sound sarcastic. Next question: are you using jQuery 1.4 yet or an earlier version?

Comment: @Rosarch: phew, now we got those questions out of the way see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/ if returning `null` is not preferable to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If rooms is empty, it is returned as {}.

Thus, it's not an array, but an object. Objects doesn't have a length. There's only one of it. If you want to denote *nothing*, then rather use `null` instead of `{}`. This way you can use `if (rooms)` instead.

To learn more about JSON, you may find [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach instead, in your situation it should be null when empty:

```
if (rooms) {
```

Comment: This looks like it's working in my minimal initial testing. Thanks.

Comment: @Rosarch: I think you'll need more testing ;)